# Avoid default warnings in form -Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms

While validating a user form am getting a default form validation pop up like this:

[image]

Here's the form with code:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required
                               data-ng-model="entity.name" name="name"
                               placeholder="Pit Name">
</form>

<button type="button" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Save</button>
```

There is a save button which on click am getting the above pop up.How can I disable that pop up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `novalidate` like

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" novalidate>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="user_email" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```